# How to remove duplicate value from session array and update it

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an session array which has many duplicate value and i want to remove the duplicate and update the session, here is what i've tried

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['arry'])) {
    $_SESSION['arry'] = array();
}
$pu = $_POST['id']; // $pu is 12, 56, 97, 34, 63 post id can be anything here

$arrys = $_SESSION[ "arry" ] = array_merge( $_SESSION[ "arry" ],explode( ",",$pu) );
$_SESSION[ "arry" ] = array_unique($arrys);
$arrys =array_map('trim',$arrys);
print_r($_SESSION[ "arry" ]); exit;
```

when i print the array

```
Array ( [0] => 269 [1] => 270 [2] => 271 [3] => 272 [4] => 271 [5] => 273 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [1] => 270 [2] => 271 [3] => 272 [4] => 271 [5] => 273 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [1] => 270 [2] => 271 [3] => 272 [4] => 271 [5] => 273 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [1] => 270 [2] => 271 [3] => 272 [4] => 271 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [3] => 270 [4] => 271 [5] => 272 [6] => 271 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [3] => 270 [4] => 271 [5] => 272 [6] => 271 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [3] => 270 [4] => 271 [5] => 272 [6] => 271 ) Array ( [0] => 269 [3] => 270 [4] => 271 )
```

Comment: Seems like this code runs in a loop?

Comment: No this code doesn't run in loop

Comment: Well then your output shown doesn't match up with the code. So either you don't show us the real code or the real output

Comment: @Rizier123 check the updated question and this all i hav

Comment: `Array(...) Array(...)` This output comes either from a multidimensional array, where you don't show us the entire array or it comes from a loop, but not from a single array output like that.

Comment: @Rizier123 every ten second the page send a ajax request to php file where this code is so then it might have worked as loop

Comment: That is probably it. Now when you do `explode()` and have a string like: `X, Y` then the space in front of the Y will stay and and makes `[sapce]Y` != `Y`. So you can try to change out `explode()` with `preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $pu)` so with this you consume all spaces(`\s`) around the comma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110226/discussion-between-sagar-singh-and-rizier123).

Comment: @Rizier123 after adding preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $pu) it gave me Array ( [0] => 273 ) so how can i add this value into my previous session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the duplicate entries out of your arrays with these two lines:

```
$arrys = array_merge( $_SESSION[ "arry" ],explode( ",", $pu) );
$_SESSION[ "arry" ] = array_unique($arrys);
```

It doesn't matter if your code is looping, as long as you are giving the same format of data to the `$_POST['id']`. The values should always be the same.

Comment: it's creating multidimensional array which i dont want Array ( [0] => 274 [1] => 275 ) Array ( [0] => 274 ) becuase after this i have to find particular value from array by in array method, i think array merge is creating multi dimensional array

Comment: I think you should close your browser and try again. Because you are storing it into a session, you are working with a multi dimensional array over and over again.

Comment: Still same problem after adding array merge it creating multi dimensional

Comment: If this doesn't work, there is probably something else not how it should be. Try to navigate to the url which your ajax request is referring to, or try to log the output of the ajax request to the console.